# Java constructor chaining and avoid code repetition

Tags: java

I have immutable class and want add new constructor without duplicating code in both constructors.

I have class:

```
public class Test {
    private final String stringParameter;

    public Test() {
        stringParameter = "firstReallyLongDefaultString";
    }

    public Test(String s) {
        stringParameter = s;
    }
}
```

And I want to add the new constructor with "char" parameter, something like this:

```
public Test(char s) {
    if(Character.isLetter(s)) {
        stringParameter = "firstReallyLong" + s + "DefaultString";
    } else {
        stringParameter = "firstReallyLongDefaultString";
    }
}
```

How can I do it without the code repetition of the long string? I would like to call "this()" constructor in else branch but it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could chain them more explicitly, removing some code repetition:

```
public class Test {
    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "firstReallyLongDefaultString";
    private final String stringParameter;

    public Test() {
        this(DEFAULT_VALUE);
    }

    public Test(String s) {
        stringParameter = s;
    }

    public Test(char c) {
        this(prepareString(c));
    }

    private static String prepareString(char c) {
        if(Character.isLetter(s)) {
            return "firstReallyLong" + s + "DefaultString";
        } else {
            return DEFAULT_VALUE;
        }
    }

}
```

The `"firstReallyLongDefaultString"` better to be done as a private constant to avoid repetition.

Comment: You mean `this` rather than `super`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Test(char s) {
    this(Character.isLetter(s) ? "firstReallyLong" + s + "DefaultString" : "firstReallyLongDefaultString");
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question... the string `firstReallyLongDefaultString` still needs to be repeated in this constructor

Comment: @Heuster that can easily be moved to a static constant

Comment: That would answer the question (unless the original constructor cannot be altered)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public Test(char s) {
    super();
    if(Character.isLetter(s)) {
        stringParameter = "firstReallyLong" + s + "DefaultString";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to compile

Comment: The property is final, this will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

A factory method gives you more flexibility:

```
public static Test create(char c) {
    final String parameter;
    if(Character.isLetter(s)) {
        parameter = "firstReallyLong" + s + "DefaultString";
    } else {
        parameter = "firstReallyLongDefaultString";
    }
    return new Test(parameter);
}
```

This can't be inherited in subclasses, however if you want your class to be strictly immutable it should be final.